# Why datepicker is not coming along with DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a datatable for some information storage and i want to bring the datapicker in it.But in the textfield i am writing the datepicker function but it is not working.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/jquery.contextMenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../css/jdpicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
     <link href="../css/table.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.contextMenu.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.jdpicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/page-common.js"></script>
  </head>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 $('#date2').jdPicker({
 date_format : "FF dd YYYY"
 });
 </script>

<body>
<br/>
<table  border="1" align="center" >
<thead>
  <tr>
  <th>DAY</th>
<th>MONTH/DATE</th>
 <th>TIME IN</th>
<th>TIME OUT</th>
 <th>LESS METAL PERIOD</th>
<th>TOTAL HOURS</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>SUNDAY</td>
  <td> <input type="text" id="date2" />

 </td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>MONDAY</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>TUESDAY</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>WEDNESDAY</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>THURSDAY</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>FRIDAY</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>SATURDAY</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>WEEK ENDING DATE(SATURDAY)</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>TOTAL HOURS TO NEAREST 1/4 HOURS</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>


</table>

</body>
</html>
```

can anyone help me with the solution

Comment: I am not able to find your #date2 and why you had used date_format : "FF dd YYYY" instead MM dd YYYY?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 $('#date2').jdPicker({
 date_format : "FF dd YYYY"
 });
 </script> this is date2

Comment: Yeah but where is your Div or Textbox in which you want the DatePicker with the same Id?

Comment: <td> <input type="text" id="date2" />

Answer (score 0):

Put this before the

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#date2').jdPicker({
 date_format : "FF dd YYYY"
 });
 </script>
```

after this put

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" ></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.jdpicker.js"></script>
```

It will work